# Java CompletableFuture.complete() block

Tags: java, multithreading, future, reactor, completable-future

I have a problem when using CompletableFuture in java.
I have 2 select requests those are filled when receiving responses from server.

In the connection thread (THREAD-1) (use reactor), I use:

```
if(hasException) {
   selectFuture.completeExceptionally(new ClientException(errorCode));
} else {
   System.out.println("Before complete future");
   selectFuture.complete(result);
   System.out.println("After complete future");
}
```

And in other thread (THREAD-2), I use:

```
CompleteFuture.allOf(allSelect).whenComplete((aVoid, throwable) -> {
   System.out.println("Receive all future");
   // Do sth here
});
```

My situation is that the system print out "Receive all future" but THREAD-1 is blocked when calling `future.complete(result);` It cannot get out of that command.
If in THREAD-2, I use `CompletableFuture.allOf(allOfSelect).get()`, the THREAD-1 will run correctly. But using `CompletableFuture.get()` reduces performance, so I would like to use `CompletableFuture.whenComplete()`.

Anyone can help me explain the cause of blocking?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `complete` call triggers all dependent `CompletionStage`s.

So if you've previously registered a `BiConsumer` with `whenComplete`, the `complete` will invoke it in its calling thread. In your case, the call to `complete` will return when the `BiConsumer` you've passed to `whenComplete` finishes. This is described in the the [class javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html)

> Actions supplied for dependent completions of non-async methods may be
>   performed by **the thread that completes the current
>   `CompletableFuture`**, or by any other caller of a completion method.

(*by another caller* is the opposite situation, where the thread calling `whenComplete` would actually apply the `BiConsumer` **if** the target `CompletableFuture` had already been completed.)

Here's a small program to illustrate the behavior:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    CompletableFuture<String> future = new CompletableFuture<String>();
    future.whenComplete((r, t) -> {
        System.out.println("before sleep, executed in thread " + Thread.currentThread());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("after sleep, executed in thread " + Thread.currentThread());
    });

    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
    future.complete("completed");
    System.out.println("done");
}
```

This will print

```
Thread[main,5,main]
before sleep, executed in thread Thread[main,5,main]
after sleep, executed in thread Thread[main,5,main]
done
```

showing that the `BiConsumer` was applied in the main thread, the one that called `complete`.

You can use [`whenCompleteAsync`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#whenCompleteAsync-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) to force execution of the `BiConsumer` in a separate thread.

> [...] that executes the given action **using this stage's default
>   asynchronous execution facility when this stage completes**.

For example,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    CompletableFuture<String> future = new CompletableFuture<String>();
    CompletableFuture<?> done = future.whenCompleteAsync((r, t) -> {
        System.out.println("before sleep, executed in thread " + Thread.currentThread());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("after sleep, executed in thread " + Thread.currentThread());
    });

    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
    future.complete("completed");
    System.out.println("done");
    done.get();
}
```

will print

```
Thread[main,5,main]
done
before sleep, executed in thread Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1,5,main]
after sleep, executed in thread Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1,5,main]
```

showing that the `BiConsumer` was applied in a separate thread.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your explanation is very clear about threading.
In my first time using CompletableFuture, I only use it to call single request from client to server (like SELECT, UPDATE, etc.), so it runs perfectly as my expectation (client wait for the response and fill the future).
But now, I have a problem with doing TRANSACTION 'cause it has stages. I wanna return the future immediately as a CompletableFuture after all SELECT done, but the future is only filled when other executions (UPDATE, DELETE) have results.
Can you suggest me a solution to process things in chain.
Many thanks!

Comment: I wanna do things in sequence like:
1. SELECT -> CompletableFuture
2. PREPARE -> CompletableFuture (do other calls those return CompletableFutures too).
3. COMMIT -> CompletableFuture
and the transaction must return immediately to the caller when I register it.
Many thanks!